# Преобразование datetime.date

Tags: python, pyqt5, pandas

Считываю данные с файла:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import math
import datetime
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.txt',
                 index_col='DATE',
                 parse_dates=True,
                 infer_datetime_format=True)

date = df.iloc[:, 0].index.date
z = df.iloc[:, 3].values

t = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
ts = t.toMSecsSinceEpoch()

print(t) #PyQt5.QtCore.QDateTime(2020, 6, 14, 1, 41, 22, 799)
print(type(t)) #<class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QDateTime'>
print(ts) #1592080882799
print(date[0]) #2018-10-30
print(type(date[0])) #<class 'datetime.date'>
```

файл находится здесь [ссылка на файл](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nzfD9K1ROEMXU4MKWoLSfp13CxUuyMSN/view)
Как мне преобразовать значения date в формат понятный для pyqt5.
Чтобы к примеру подставить значение `date[0]` вместо `currentDateTime()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> QDate QDate::fromString(const QString &string, Qt::DateFormat format = Qt::TextDate)
>
> Возвращает QDate, представленную строкой, используя заданный формат, или недопустимую дату,  если строка не может быть проанализирована.

---

> QDateTime::QDateTime(const QDate &date)
>
> Создает datetime с заданной датой, используя Qt::LocalTime в качестве timeSpec() и время в начале этой даты.

---

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import math
import datetime
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('file.txt',
                 index_col='DATE',
                 parse_dates=True,
                 infer_datetime_format=True)

date = df.iloc[:, 0].index.date
z = df.iloc[:, 3].values

t = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
ts = t.toMSecsSinceEpoch()

print(t)             # PyQt5.QtCore.QDateTime(2020, 6, 14, 1, 41, 22, 799)
print(type(t))       # <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QDateTime'>

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

dateQDate = QDate.fromString('2020-06-14', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
print(f'\ndateQDate = {dateQDate}')

dateQDate = QDate.fromString(str(date[0]), 'yyyy-MM-dd')      # <---------
print(f'dateQDate = {dateQDate}\n')

dateTime = QDateTime(dateQDate)                               # <---------
print(f'dateTime = {dateTime}\n')

dateTime2 = QDateTime(date[0])                                 # <=========
print(f'dateTime2 = {dateTime2}\n')

# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


print(ts)            # 1592080882799
print(date[0])       # 2018-10-30
print(type(date[0])) # <class 'datetime.date'>
```

Comment: @inquirer я обновил свой ответ

Comment: Если  правильно понимаю, то придется два раза преобразовывать данные QDate.fromString и QDateTime функциями?

Comment: @inquirer я еще раз обновил ответ. `dateTime2 = QDateTime(date[0])`

Comment: Понял использую только одну функцию QDateTime(date[i]).toMSecsSinceEpoch(). Все получилось, на графике появились значения QDateTime по нужной мне оси.